# I'm trying to load data into my oracle table using sql loader

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes, sql-loader

This is my table...it has `Number` as a column name

```
CREATE TABLE pwc_it_service (
  "SEQ"                  NUMBER,
  "NUMBER"               VARCHAR2(10),
  "CI_NAME"              VARCHAR2(200),
  "CI_CLASS"             VARCHAR2(200),
  "OWNED_BY_PRIMARY"     VARCHAR2(200),
  "OWNED_BY_SECONDARY"   VARCHAR2(200),
  "MANAGING_TERRITORY"   VARCHAR2(200),
  "LOS"                  VARCHAR2(100),
  "BUSINESS_UNIT"        VARCHAR2(100),
  "IMPORTED"             DATE,
  "LAST_UPDATED"         DATE
)
```

When i run my ctl file, i get the below error:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table PWC_IT_SERVICE, column NUMBER.
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

how can i insert the values without changing column name

Comment: What does the SQL*Loader control file look like?

Comment: show the the CTL file AND the data you're trying to load - also which schema does the table belong to vs which user are you running sqlldr as ?

Answer (score 1):

It was really a bad idea naming the column `"NUMBER"` (yes, double quotes and uppercase included). The fact that you can do it doesn't mean that you should do it. Now you have to deal with it and use the same *syntax* all the time - double quotes and uppercase. Have a look:

```
SQL> create table test ("NUMBER" varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (number) values ('A');
insert into test (number) values ('A')
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword


SQL> insert into test ("number") values ('A');
insert into test ("number") values ('A')
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "number": invalid identifier


SQL> insert into test ("NUMBER") values ('A');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Do the same in the control file.

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table test
( 
"NUMBER" terminated by whitespace
)

begindata
Little
Foot
```

How it works?

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                          Null?    Type
 ----------------------------- -------- --------------------
 NUMBER                                 VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@xe control=test02.ctl log=test02.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sri Svi 23 22:23:07 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

SQL> select * From test;

NUMBER
----------
Little
Foot

SQL>
```

Works fine.

However, I'd suggest you to rename that unforunate column.  Get rid of double quotes, now and forever.